# Moving from California to Washington state - Payout for unused vacation?

Tags: management, resignation, human-resources, vacation, compensation

I worked full time for a company for many years from the San Francisco bay area region in California, USA. After discussion with my manager, I gave notice to quit in November 2019 and my last day is in January 2020.

I moved to Seattle, Washington in Dec 2019. I will be working remotely until my last day. Meanwhile, my company will be looking for my replacement. As an aside, my manager mentioned that by allowing me to continue working till early Jan 2020, I might be eligible for bonuses.

I have accrued about a month of paid vacation time in California state which requires payout of unused vacation time when an employee is fired, laid off or quits. However, Washington state does not require such payouts. So, I am concerned that my company might not pay me for unused vacation time upon quitting. That might be legally acceptable, but it feels wrong or unethical to me. I did not get any satisfactory written/emailed answers to my concern from HR, most of which was recently moved overseas.

I was wondering if I should consult an lawyer to find out if I am still legally entitled to vacation payout ? If yes, then which kind of lawyer would be best and which state should they be licensed in ?

Alternately, I was wondering if I should ask my company to give in writing that I will be paid for unused vacation time. I could threaten to quit before Jan 2020 if they do not put it in writing.

**UPDATE 1:**
My employee portal says that vacation for non-california states is capped at N days. It does NOT carry over. My understanding is that if I have more than N days accrued during my time at California, then I get to keep it all in 2019. But, for 2020, I might start with zero vacation. I would then have to accrue N days. I am trying to figure it out after emailing HR.

**UPDATE 2 :**
I am in the process of giving KT to a new member in our team. Most of it is done, but he might need more help. Hence, any big vacation requests will likely be denied because Managers have the right to do so per our employee poilcy.

Please advise.

Comment: Do you have an employment contract or employee handbook that spells out how your unused vacation is paid out? Regardless of the laws, if your contract states it, you are entitled to it.

Comment: I'm certain that the law applies to where the company resides, not the employee... but you should ask a lawyer... one who practices employment law in the state where the company resides.

Comment: How much vacation do they owe you? Why threaten to quit? You could just threaten to take all your vacation days right now if they do not put this down in writing. This way, if they fire you because of that, you could still file for unemployment at least.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - I prefer email responses to keep proof of all communications should the need arise to use them. But, I can try phone also. The recording will require a bit of effort. I might have to ask the offshore hr person to identify themselves so that it goes on record.

Comment: @noslenkwah - I have updated my question with that information.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk - they owe me about a month of vacation. Our HR policy requires that we request our manager for vacation. Also, managers have the right to deny our request. Since I am giving KT to another employee, its likely that any big vacation request will be denied.

Comment: @joeqwerty - My company has offices in many cities in many states. How do I find out where is their USA HQ ?

Comment: In any case, don't threaten to quit before consulting a lawyer. I don't know if it's possible, but if you quit, you might want to move back to California before you do any of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in a sticky situation.  IF your employer transitioned your place of employment, which they should have, then you are now governed under those states laws.  However, if the company has most of their people in CA their 'policy' may be to pay out vacation now matter where you live.

Remote workers provide interesting problems for companies, especially small ones, and the outsourced HR makes it even more complicated depending on their knowledge and experience with remote workers.

To properly have you working in Washington, they need to be registered in Washington.  They need to be withholding your Washington state taxes etc.  They probably did not realize the mess this caused when they agreed to this plan.  I had something similar, and the cost to get the business license in the state I moved to for remote work was $10k.  CA has some very interesting laws including that any time you are in the state earning a salary, even if just visiting a remote office, you must pay CA taxes.

You created this mess when you moved prematurely.  You will have to just deal with it at this point.  Hopefully it is just their policy to pay out no matter the work location.  There really is not much other recourse, and bringing it up with HR will just make them take a second look at the whole thing.

Comment: And I guess this is where the lawyer will say to the OP "Hmm, you seem to be working illegally in Washington. I need to look into that."

Comment: @Nelson - yeah. I did not know about that.

Comment: Bill, please explain this "and bringing it up with HR will just make them take a second look at the whole thing.". 

Btw, you brought up a good point about the company being registered in Washington state. That is another complication.

Comment: @catowa If you accept what HR is offering, they won't really look into the issue. However, if you can go lawyer up and threaten them, they'll then be forced to lawyer up too, then the lawyer will say what I said above, and probably make you pay for the licensing fee. Basically, the less you rock the boat the better at this point. You can probably still refer to a lawyer, but you are not exactly in the clear due to the move being initiated by yourself. The company can simply fire you on the spot so they don't have to deal with the licensing issue.

Comment: Bill, how do I find out ON MY OWN if my company is registered in Washington, and what are Washington's registration requirements, fees etc. ? Sorry for the caps. Thanks.

Comment: You don't, it's their problem honestly.  What you can find or should be able to find is standard termination policies.  I got a packet when I resigned from my last job and the other information was buried in the employee manual.  That will tell you if the payout is standard or only in certain states.  In my case it was only in states like CA that required it.  Also make sure when you file your year end taxes you properly account for the time you worked in CA and WA.   It is only an issue if you have a law in WA that is not in CA that you want the company to honor.

Comment: @BillLeeper - They did take a second look at the whole thing and now, my vacation hours are halved to match the rest of the country which is no match for the golden state of CA.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you escalate the situation?
IMHO, notify your direct manager and use your vacation time until the end of the 2019

This way, entire issue is moot.

This will also allow your manager to reach out to you with plan for vacation usage in other ways, and you will have a paper trail for your options