# Resigning next day

Tags: united-states, resignation, manager

I had already given notice of about 1.5 months to leave my current employer. This is more than the courtesy 2 weeks notice, considering that my contract states at will employment. It is about a month now since I gave my notice.

I was promised certain amount of vacation payout which I am likely not going to get. The history about that is here, if you are interested [USA Resignation - Changing the last day at a company](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/149490/usa-resignation-changing-the-last-day-at-a-company)

If I don't get what was promised to me, then I would like to quit the next day. Could this cause any problems for me now or later ? Any advice on how to make a quick exit ?

Comment: Well, they might give you a bad reference.

Comment: I read your last post. How come you've still not got this agreed in writing? Perhaps things work different outside of the US, but if I'd raised this issue, I'd expect to have had it resolved within 1 or 2 days. I hope you get what you're owed.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk - Which reference are you talking about ? I don't want or need any reference. I just pursue jobs which don't ask for references because IMO employers who give it too much importance are being too lazy about vetting.

Comment: @fubar - I did not get it agreed in writing, but I got the email from hr in which my manager had asked that I be classified as CA employee. I will push for this explicitly and see what happens.

Comment: @catowa - I wonder whether you have a case in that the PTO was earned in CA, and therefore should be paid as such, irrespective of your current location. Good luck!

Comment: "I just pursue jobs which don't ask for references" That's fine then.

Comment: @fubar - I don't have a case. They can get away with it on a technicality. Legal and fair are not the same things.

Answer (score 4):

> If I don't get what was promised to me, then I would like to quit the
>   next day. Could this cause any problems for me now or later?

It could potentially burn bridges with this employer and anyone who works there. You may not get a decent reference.

> Any advice on how to make a quick exit?

Decide if you care or not, then act accordingly.

If you don't get what you want, and don't care about burning bridges, and you thus want to leave the next day, then just leave the next day.

In an at-will employment state, you can walk out the same day if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see the need for references and I prefer jobs which don't ask for them. IMO most employers are just being lazy when they ask for references, or past salary. I am only worried if it will *surely* cause problems for future employment.

Comment: It'll **surely** cause problems if your next employer calls them. It'll of course do nothing if they don't. Whether your next employer will call or not is up to them and nobody on the internet will know.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - What if the employer is at fault and is seeking revenge from the departing employee ? Wouldn't their reference be negatively biased ? I don't know if companies even give the accused a chance to defend themselves. If not, then such a system of vetting seems pretty shoddy to me.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - I was not talking about giving reference. I meat the new employer talking directly to the old one as Nelson suggested. Can the new one do that without my permission ?

Comment: Not understanding how checking references works is probably a separate question, but no they don't need your permission and yes many will call up the previous employer to verify your employment dates, how you left, and whatever else they will tell them.  Be a professional and move your exit date up to a shorter time, but "tomorrow" is just spiteful and they will react accordingly.  I suspect many of your problems resulting in this big chain of questions is from a lack of effective collaboration.